# Do the DNS servers make Bitcoin more secure than the IRC channel?

Tags: security, dns, irc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How secure are the DNS servers for Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3541/how-secure-are-the-dns-servers-for-bitcoin)

In earlier version of Bitcoin the IRC channel was used to seed initial peers, and as of version 0.6 it was largely replaced by the DNS servers. Does this approach make Bitcoin more secure, and if so, in what way?

Comment: I wouldn't say this is an exact duplicate. This question is focused on whether adding DNS servers to the standard client makes it more secure, while the other question deals solely with the security of Bitcoin DNSs.

Comment: I've posted an answer there that covers both interpretations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS system is vastly more scalable than an IRC channel. It has its downsides, in particular it is only unidirectional. However, given enough seeds it is much harder to knock out than a centralized IRC server.

Comment: Please re-post your answer to [this question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3541/how-secure-are-the-dns-servers-for-bitcoin).